# Java Menubar Action to a Class

Tags: java, swing, sockets, static, action

I have a java menubar in my program that just has 1 option with 2 sub-options, e.g. File -> Save, Close. But instead of Save and Close, my options are Server and Client. So for the action event for the 1st option I have this java action listener:

```
public class serverAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public serverAction()
        {
            super();
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
        }

    }
```

So this works when I click on File->Server, it pops up a window that says Test. Now I have a server class (That I have tested separately and know it works) that looks like this:

```
public class SocketServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
    }   
    private static class ClientListenThread extends Thread {        
        public ClientListenThread(Socket socket, int ClientNumber){
            ...
        }       
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }

    private static class ServerSendThread extends Thread {      
        public ServerSendThread(Socket socket) {
            ...
        }       
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to call this `SocketServer` class when I click on the server option of my main program so that it can start the server code and wait and listen for any client connections. My question is, how do I start the entire `SocketServer` class code from the `serverAction` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [nested-classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) are `private` that means that are only visible in `ServerSocket` class. So you can provide a helper method with more visibility or change class declaration signature with more visibility.

Example with helper method:

```
public class SocketServer {
.
.
 //nested classes declaration    
 public static void startServer(){
   //code to start threads new SomeThread().start();
 }    
}
```

And in your action

```
public class ServerAction extends AbstractAction{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            SocketServer.startServer();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test"); 
        }
}
```

It would be great if you can notify when a client is connected and so on, I'd recommend you to take a look to `SwingWorker` that provide helpful tool to handle notification between a background thread and the gui thread.

Read more: [Worker threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Note : Would be great if you implements `Runnable` rather to extend Thread, you are not adding any special functionality to thread there is no reason, more details here --> ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread).

Comment: so would I call the `main` function from `startServer()`?

Comment: @Richard No, the main is the entry point of your app. There you create your `gui`, when you click in the menu `Server` ..`actionPerformed` is executed and there you start the server.

Comment: @nackhokk additionally, is there an easy way to make java windows (like a drag-n-drop gui that'll write the code for me?) instead of me having to spend hours trying to get the alignment right in the code?

Comment: @Richard You can use Netbeans gui builder (a.k.a Matisse) that comes with netbeans, but if not you can start learning about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)